# Why isn't my array updating even though it updates when I console.log()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a booking system and when someone books a time, I made it so that it removes the time from the database which works fine. Here you can see what my database looks like: [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5YhY.png). I want to setTimes to the times array in the database since its already working properly but everytime I setTimes(doc.data().times) it returns the original array without the removed time. When I console.log the(doc.data().times), I get two logs from the same line and the first one is the one I want to show on the screen because it has the time removed but the second one shows up on the screen which still has the time. Here's a picture of the console: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2gdi.png).

```
function GThirtyminsp() {
  const style = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: 400,
    bgcolor: "background.paper",
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
  };

  // Form values
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [team, setTeam] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const handleErrOpen = () => setError(true);
  const handleErrClose = () => setError(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  // To show times on screen
  const [times, setTimes] = useState([]);

  const timesRef = collection(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate-times");
  const formRef = collection(db, "30min-goalie-semiprivate");

  const createBooking = async () => {
    await addDoc(formRef, {
      name: name,
      date: date,
      email: email,
      number: number,
      team: team,
      age: age,
      time: time,
    });
  };

  const addTimesForNextThreeWeeks = async () => {
    // Get current date
    let currentDate = new Date();

    // Set times to generate for weekdays
    let times = [];

    // Check if current day is Monday
    if (currentDate.getDay() === 1) {
      // Generate times for next three weeks
      for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        // Format date as string
        const formattedDate = currentDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

        // Check if current date is a Saturday or Sunday
        if (currentDate.getDay() === 6 || currentDate.getDay() === 0) {
          // Set times to generate for Saturdays and Sundays
          times = [
            "Select a Time",
            "7:00am",
            "7:30am",
            "8:00am",
            "8:30am",
            "9:00am",
            "9:30am",
            "10:00am",
            "10:30am",
            "11:00am",
            "11:30am",
            "12:00pm",
            "12:30pm",
            "1:00pm",
            "1:30pm",
            "2:00pm",
            "2:30pm",
            "3:00pm",
            "3:30pm",
            "4:00pm",
            "4:30pm",
            "5:00pm",
            "5:30pm",
            "6:00pm",
            "6:30pm",
            "7:00pm",
            "7:30pm",
            "8:00pm",
            "8:30pm",
          ];
        } else {
          // Set times to generate for weekdays
          times = [];
        }

        // Add the times for this date to the database
        await addDoc(timesRef, {
          date: formattedDate,
          times: times,
        });

        // Increment current date by 1 day
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(times);

  const handleDateChange = async (selectedDate) => {
    const dateToday = new Date();
    const enteredDate = new Date(date);
    const threeWeeksInMilliseconds = 3 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    setDate(selectedDate);
    if (selectedDate) {
      console.log(
        "Fetching data for date: ",
        selectedDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
      );

      const timeQuery = query(
        timesRef,
        where("date", "==", selectedDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10))
      );

      const qSnap = await getDocs(timeQuery);

      if (enteredDate - dateToday > threeWeeksInMilliseconds) {
        setTimes([]);
        console.log("no available times");
      } else {
        qSnap.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log("These are the times: ", doc.data().times);
          setTimes(doc.data().times);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const countFunction = async () => {
    const countSnap = getCountFromServer(timesRef);
    console.log((await countSnap).data().count);

    if ((await countSnap).data().count < 21) {
      addTimesForNextThreeWeeks();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    countFunction();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      name === "" ||
      email === "" ||
      date === null ||
      time === "" ||
      time === "Select a Time" ||
      age === "" ||
      team === "" ||
      number === ""
    ) {
      handleErrOpen();
    } else {
      handleOpen();
      createBooking();

      const readableDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
        month: "long",
        day: "numeric",
        year: "numeric",
      });

      const service = "30min goalie clinic - semiprivate";

      const res = await fetch("/bookings", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          number,
          team,
          age,
          readableDate,
          time,
          service,
        }),
      });

      setName("");
      setEmail("");
      setDate(null);
      setNumber("");
      setTeam("");
      setTime("");
      setAge("");
    }

    const timeQuery = query(
      timesRef,
      where("date", "==", date.toISOString().slice(0, 10))
    );
    const qSnap = await getDocs(timeQuery);

    // Get the document ID and times array
    qSnap.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log("id: ", doc.id, "data: ", doc.data());
    });

    let updatedTimes = times.filter((t) => t !== time);
    if (times.length === 1) {
      updatedTimes = [];
    }

    if (qSnap.size > 0) {
      const docId = qSnap.docs[0].id;
      const docRef = doc(timesRef, docId);
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        times: updatedTimes,
      });
    }

    handleDateChange(date);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-3xl w-full text-center pt-10 font-bold">
        Book 30min Semi-Private Goalie Clinic
      </h1>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} class="flex flex-col pt-10 w-3/4">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="number"
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            value={number}
            onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="team"
            placeholder="Team Name"
            value={team}
            onChange={(e) => setTeam(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="age"
            placeholder="Age"
            value={age}
            onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
            class="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg"
          />
          <h2 class="text-center text-xl py-5 font-bold">
            Pick a Date and Time
          </h2>
          <p class="text-sm pb-5 text-center font-light">
            Please note that we only allow bookings up to 3 weeks in advance.
            Please choose a date within the next 3 weeks.
          </p>
          <p class="text-sm pb-7 text-center font-light">
            If there are no time slots available please select another date or
            try refreshing the page.
          </p>
          <p class="text-sm pb-7 text-center font-semibold">
            The available times for our Goalie Clinics are Sat-Sun: 7am-9pm.
          </p>
          <div class="pb-10">
            <DatePicker
              className="border-2 p-3 w-full border-gray rounded-lg"
              selected={date}
              onChange={handleDateChange}
              placeholderText="Select a Date"
            />
            <div class="pt-10">
              <select
                value={time}
                onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Choose a Time"
                className="border-2 p-3 mb-5 border-gray rounded-lg w-full"
              >
                {times.map((time) => (
                  <option key={Math.random() * 10000000} value={time}>
                    {time}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button
            type="submit"
            class="bg-accent text-white font-semibold p-3 rounded-full"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
        <Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box sx={style}>
            <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
              Thanks For Booking!
            </Typography>
            <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2, py: 3 }}>
              Please check your email for booking conformation.
            </Typography>
            <button
              onClick={handleClose}
              class="bg-blue text-white text-sm font-normal p-3 rounded-full w-full"
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          open={error}
          onClose={handleErrClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box sx={style}>
            <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
              Uh Oh!
            </Typography>
            <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2, py: 3 }}>
              Please make sure all fields are filled in.
            </Typography>
            <button
              onClick={handleErrClose}
              class="bg-blue text-white text-sm font-normal p-3 rounded-full w-full"
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GThirtyminsp;
```

Comment: What do you think `forEach` does?

Comment: useState hooks aren't called synchronously, so calling setTimes in a forEach loop like this is likely a bad idea. Would `qSnap[0].data().times` work?

Comment: @Allie Howe no that doesnt work

Comment: @Konrad yes I realized that wouldn't work. Would would I have to do then?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Firestore as your database and you are trying to update the state of the times array on the frontend to reflect the updated times array in the database. However, it seems that the state is not updating correctly because you are using the setTimes(doc.data().times) function inside a Firestore snapshot function, which is asynchronous. This means that by the time the snapshot function runs and updates the state, the component may have already rendered with the previous state.

To solve this, you should make sure that the setTimes function is only called after the component has rendered. One way to achieve this is by using the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  timesRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    setTimes(snapshot.data().times);
  });
}, []);
```

You should also make sure that you are only calling the `setTimes` function once in the createBooking function.

```
const createBooking = async () => {
    await addDoc(formRef, {
      name: name,
      date: date,
      email: email,
      number: number,
      team: team,
      age: age,
      time: time,
    });
    await timesRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setTimes(snapshot.data().times);
    });
  };
```

Additionally, it could be an issue with the way you are handling the current day of the week, check if the current day is a valid day.

Comment: where would the useEffect be used?

Comment: It's React hook, You can import it from react

Comment: Yes I know that but, when I use it, it gives me an error. And what would be in the else {} now